# Recursive Tkinter Notebook

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

I try to build an app with a notebook in which I don't really know the number of things that would go into it. I mean by things, tabs and subtabs and subtabs of subtabs. I decided to code a custom widget that will allow me to only give a dictionary in argument and voilà.
I maybe do not seem clear so hear my example. Graphically it is fully working but when we look deeply into the *notebook.tabs* dictionary, well, it is not.

```
from tkinter import ttk
# Custom Tkinter Widget
class NotebookPlus(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, schema=None, **kwargs):
        ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.schema = schema
        self.tabs = {}

        def superiterdict(dictionnary, lastK=None, lastN=None):

            for key, value in dictionnary.items():
                if lastN == None: lastN = self

                # With multiple layer of notebook
                if isinstance(value, dict):

                    # Create a new principal notebook
                    self.tabs[key] = {}

                    # Define the frame where the new notebook will be and where tabs are going to be
                    self.tabs[key]['frame'] = ttk.Frame(lastN)
                    self.tabs[key]['frame'].pack(fill='both')

                    # Define the new notebook
                    self.tabs[key]['notebook'] = ttk.Notebook(self.tabs[key]['frame'])
                    self.tabs[key]['notebook'].pack(fill='both')

                    lastN.add(self.tabs[key]['frame'], text=key)

                    # Define tabs
                    self.tabs[key]['tabs'] = {}

                    superiterdict(dictionnary=value, lastK=key, lastN=self.tabs[key]['notebook'])

                else:
                    if self.tabs == {} and lastK == None:
                        self.tabs[lastK] = {'frame':None, 'notebook':lastN, 'tabs':{}}
                    self.tabs[lastK]['tabs'][key] = ttk.Frame(lastN)
                    self.tabs[lastK]['tabs'][key].pack(fill='both')
                    self.tabs[lastK]['notebook'].add(self.tabs[lastK]['tabs'][key], text=key)

        superiterdict(self.schema)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
tabsSchema = {'TAB1': {'subtab11': None, 'subtab12': None},
              'TAB2': {'subtab21': {'ssubtab211': None, 'ssubtab212': None}, 'subtab22': None}
              }
notebook = NotebookPlus(root,schema=tabsSchema)
notebook.pack(fill='both')


root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that each time that the recursive function superiterdict is in front with a dictionary, it is treated as a completely new tab but sometimes it is not. To see that, here is the dictionary where everything is thrown in.

```
{
    'TAB1': {
        'frame': 'blob',
        'notebook': 'blob',
        'tabs': {
                'subtab11': 'blob',
                'subtab12': 'blob'
                }
        },
    'TAB2': {
            'frame': 'blob',
            'notebook': 'blob',
            'tabs': {
                    'subtab22':'blob'
                    }
        },
    'subtab21': {
                'frame': 'blob',
                'notebook': 'blob',
                'tabs': {
                        'ssubtab211': 'blob',
                        'ssubtab212': 'blob'
                        }
                    }
}
```

I use 'blob' instead of '<tkinter.ttk.Frame object .!notebookplus.!frame2.!notebook.!frame2>' for readability. We can notice that the *'subtab21'* is not in the tab dictionary of *TAB2*.

Comment: The ttk.Notebook class has the [tabs()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.tabs) method. Better to use a different name. Not `self.tabs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `self.tabs` to add to the dictionary each time. This means that every time a key has a dictionary as it's value, that key is getting added to `self.tabs` instead of the tabs dictionary of the parent.  You want to add to the `tabs` dictionary of the parent instead.

Here is a working `superiterdict` function:

```
def superiterdict(dictionary, lastN = self, lastK = self.tabs):
            # lastN: The widget to use as the parent.
            # lastK: The "tabs" dictionary of the parent.
            #        If not given, it defaults to self.tabs.
            for key, value in dictionary.items():
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    lastK[key] = {}
                    lastK[key]["frame"] = ttk.Frame(lastN)
                    lastK[key]["frame"].pack(fill = "both")
                    lastN.add(lastK[key]["frame"], text = key)
                    lastK[key]["notebook"] = ttk.Notebook(lastK[key]["frame"])
                    lastK[key]["notebook"].pack(fill = "both")
                    lastK[key]["tabs"] = {}
                    superiterdict(value, lastN = lastK[key]["notebook"], lastK = lastK[key]["tabs"])
                else:
                    lastK[key] = ttk.Frame(lastN)
                    lastK[key].pack(fill = "both")
                    lastN.add(lastK[key], text = key)
```

This provides `self.tabs` in the desired format.